# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Recognizer'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I'm using python's [Speach Recognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) and my code is giving me an `AttributeError`:

```
import os
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

def excel():
        os.system("start excel.exe")

def internet():
        os.system("start chrome.exe")

def media():
        os.system("start wmplayer.exe")

def mainfunction(source):
    audio = r.listen(source)
    user = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(user)
    if user == "Excel":
        excel()
    elif user == "Internet":
        internet()
    elif user == "music":
        media()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = sr.Recognizer()    #this is the line that fails
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        while 1:
            mainfunction(source)
```

the error message is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Recognizer'
(test-dev-pro)➜  ~  python speech_recognition.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speech_recognition.py", line 26, in <module>
    r = sr.Recognizer()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Recognizer'
```

but `Recognizer` is used in all the examples I have looked at so I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Show your code, What exactly you are trying to do

Comment: And format your code as explained in the edit view. You can edit your question by clicking an the **edit** link below your question. Also please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I am trying to do a simple speech recognition python program. i am new to python so please consider my mistakes. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you call your file `speech_recognition` and try to import a module called `speech_recognition` from a library? if that is the case you need to rename your file because the import will just import it's own file.

Comment: to test my theory add `print ("TEST")` right below `import speech_recognition as sr` and if it prints twice then you are importing your own file, which I can explain in an answer.

Comment: I renamed my file as test123.py , even though i am getting the same error.please help someone

Comment: You would want to look for and delete speach_recognition.pyc located in either the same folder or a subfolder called __pycache__.

Comment: Yeah..now it works....Thank uu sooo much....

Comment: Anyone who finds this question, the generic solution is answered inL [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 4):

You are having the same issue as this: [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

by naming your file `speach_recognition` you end up importing your own file instead of the library file.  To fix this just change the name of your file and you'll be good to go! :)

Edit: be sure to look at the comments on that question as well for info cleaning up the .pyc file as well.

Comment: I renamed my file as test123.py , even though i am getting the same error.please help someone.

Comment: try moving to new folder and rerunning, it may be a `.pyc` file in the folder or a `__pycache__` subfolder

Comment: you would want to look for and delete `speach_recognition.pyc` located in either the same folder or a subfolder called `__pycache__`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your source file name is speech_recognition.py, This is conflict the methods with in the speech recognition package. So just change the name of the file. 
If occurs another error like

`AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize`'

then just change the recognize() method as google_recognize()

Answer (score 0):

People on Windows may face problem with `pyaudio` I faced the same

```
pip install pipwin
```

After installing `pipwin`

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

It will help you